# eslint rules about recursively prettify object literal with proper indent?

Tags: eslint

I want

```
{a:1,bc:{c:2,cd:2}}
```

can be auto fixed by eslint like:

```
{
  a : 1,
  bc: {
    c : 2,
    cd: 2
  }
}
```

i.e. when the value is object or array literal, the eslint will not only insert newline but also make more indent accordingly. I know `object-property-newline` rule, but it doesn't handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

I tested by right click and `Format Document` and worked! but eslint got error because your wrong syntax and the correct codes is:

```
{
 a: 1;
 bc: {
  c: 2;
  cd: 2;
 }
}
```